# Adword or web traffic dataset

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, releasing-data

looking for a website traffic analysis dataset for the project ASAP. can you direct me to any resources to download free datasets of such kind?

Comment: Please give us some more info. What should a *traffic analysis dataset* contain? How do the adwords you mention in the title relate to this? What kind of project? How much data? From one or multiple  websites? Etc. [Read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) to help improve your question. And when you [edit] the question, remove the ASAP - that sounds demanding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do a google search using, *inurl:access.log filetype:log*, then you’ll find tons of website log files to download.